# Chrome rendering css files as style tags in the element inspector

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome version: 44

When working in my normal development environment (C#, IIS Express) css files downloaded by the browser are available in the sources tab and I can see what styles come from what files in the element inspector. However, in my current development environment (PHP, Apache, Xammp). The stylesheets are being downloaded and rendered as style tags and are not available in the sources tab. This is rather annoying as I can't save locally edited styles to my working copy. I've never seen this before and can't seem to find any answers with a quick google. Does anyone know what would cause dev tools to render this way? I feel like it must be some sort of server configuration issue but I can't be sure. Example below:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

is rendered as:

[image]

And looks like so in the element inspector:

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a live site we can inspect? If not what is the actual source code sent to browsers? Looks like something in your backend application is modifying the link's to be style elements which is causing the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no live site. I thought it was something to do with the server at first. However, when I view the page source the css links appear as links not as style tags. It seems they are being transformed into style tags by chrome. This does not happen on all pages on the site.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`N` to open an incognito mode Chrome window to see if this still exist. If so, this may be made by some extension.

Answer (score 1):

I just met the same issue. Not sure if my case can fix your problem, but I found out that I had a script 'prefixfree' requesting redundant css files at loading. So I just commented this line out and my style in Element Inspector just back to normal.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/prefixfree-1.0.7.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem appeared to be caused by a bad/malformed CSS style that was being applied to the target element. I'm able access the element's style normally after removing this style:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#2521BC), to(#1C1957), color-stop(.5,#3A33E7));
```